# Netsuite API for Application Performance Monitor SuiteApp

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Is there any suitescript API to pull the **Application Performance Monitor** metrics from the NS database or any other alternate way to get this data. We need the data to store for future reference to optimize the transaction records. Can anyone please help in this to get the data? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not public but yes you can make requests to the underlying Suitelets that power the NetSuite APM. To see this, go to one of the APM modules, inspect the page and choose the network tab. Once this is open, you can refresh the data and then inspect the request that was made to fetch the data used to populate these metrics.

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, Thank you Steffen. I will check.